# Analyze a social flying service

Tags: ordinal-data, likert

I am writing a dissertation to obtain a Master's degree in Business Administration, but have no solid experience in statistical analysis. I have to analyze data from questionnaire in SPSS and I am using SPSS Statistics 20 on Windows 8.

**Questionnaire:**

How would you measure the attractiveness of the following functionalities in a social flying service? (1-not interested at all; 4-very interested)

- See other passenger’s social media profile
- See other passenger’s final destination
- Choose a seatmate based on social media profile
- Share your social media profile to other passengers
- Share your final destination to other passengers
- Share your seat position with other passengers (they can choose to
  seat next to you)
- Use the in-flight messaging system to chat with other passengers
- Exchange drinks or snacks with other passengers

If you came across with such social flying service, how likely are you to…? (1-very unlikely; 4-very likely)

- Prefer this airline against competitors
- Pay more for a flight that offers such social flying experience
- Fly with this airline regularly
- Switch from competitors to this airline
- Become more attentive to this company’s future campaigns and
  offerings
- Recommend this airline to friends
- Look at this airline first next time you travel

I would like to consider all the first set of items as "Attitude towards social flying service" and second set of items as "Loyalty-related behavior"

My research goals are:

- Understand the attitude of consumers towards social flying service. Positive or negative? (ie if they are interested such service)
- Understand if differences on such attitude (rankings) between groups by gender and age are statistically significant.
- Understand if attitude towards the service is associated with loyalty behaviors (e.g. word of mouth - I want to understand if those who have a more positive attitude towards the service are more likely to engage in loyalty-related behaviors"
- Understand if age and gender have moderating roles on relationship between attitude and loyalty.

I obtained 340 responses (160 females and 180 males).

What would be your advice in order to answer these research goals?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible, I would suggest using standard or semi-standard (customized) survey instruments versus creating your own from the scratch. You would have to review research literature in your domain and maybe social sciences, in general.

Comment: Thanks for your input Aleksandr Blekh. Unfortunately, I am rushing to meet a deadline and I have collected 340 responses and I have serious doubts that anyone would be willing to answer another questionnaire. Is there anything I can do (in terms of statistical analysis) with the data gathered in order to achieve my research goals?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry I misunderstood your situation. In terms of your question, I'm sure that other people here will help you with some useful advice. I don't have any answer or advice at this time, but will return to your question and will see, if there is any advice that I could share with you.

Comment: Is this the same study you ask about in [your previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133108/how-to-analyze-this-data-from-questionnaire)?

Comment: Yes but I thought I was not clear enough in the previous one. Should I delete it?

Comment: I deleted it for you.  Please do not post the same question multiple times--just edit it in response to any comments you might get.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts and suggestions.  With respect to your first understand statement, decide which questions are relevant and then report descriptive statistics for each.  WRT your second understand statement, you could look at each question separately or you could form a scale from several or all the questions.  The choice depends on whether you think the topic in each individual question is interesting in itself.  If you look at individual questions, you might then do chi-square tests to test for differences between gender or between age groups on each question.  (If you do this, use an alpha level lower than .05, since you will be doing many such tests and you expect 5% of such tests to be significant by chance.)  If you form a scale, you could do a Mann-Whitney U test between genders or a rank-order correlation between scale score and age.  WRT your third understand statement, can you clarify what you mean by "word of mouth" - I do not see a question on that.  Your last understand statement can be addressed in a manner similar to that described for your second statement.